# PDO fetchAll() returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm executing a simple query, without bound parameters, using PDO. I have tested it directly against my database and it executes cleanly, returning the expected results. However, when I plug it in to my PDO object and call `fetchAll()`, it returns an empty array.

```
$query = 'SELECT count(*) as mycount FROM mytable';
$mysql = $connection->prepare($query);
$result = $mysql->fetchAll();

print_r($result);
```

Expected result:

```
array
(
    [mycount] => 8
)
```

Actual result:

```
array
(
)
```

Any ideas what might be causing this, or how to go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've prepared, but haven't executed the statement. You need

```
$mysql->execute();
```

first

Comment: Adding: If you don't need to bind parameters, use `PDO::query` instead of preparing a statement...

Answer (score 4):

First you need to:

```
$mysql->execute();
```

Then you can

```
$result = $mysql->fetchAll();
```